# how to create xml message in c?

Tags: c, xml

My application is written in c, and I need to create some XML messages to send over HTTP.

what's the best way to create XML messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: [POCO project](http://pocoproject.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's your platform, and what are your requirements?  If you're just on Windows and you don't want to rely on 3rd party libraries, you'll be looking into msxml.  You could use xerces if you are amenable to 3rd party; if you're on some flavor of linux, the story continues to change.

So basically, what are your requirements?

Comment: I am using windows, not linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is [libxml-2.0](http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html) and [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/).  Libxml-2.0 supports [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) but expat supports just [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML).