# How to generate a xml file in C

Tags: c, xml

I want to generate a xml file through my C application and add entries to it dynamically. I almost know what should my xml look like, i mean its schema. Please let me know how to accomplish this in C.

Comment: See [how to create xml message in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366316/how-to-create-xml-message-in-c).

Comment: The cited post doesn't mention either expat (a "classic" choice) or Xerces (arguably one of the best libraries available)

Answer (score 5):

You can use an xml library like **[minixml](http://www.minixml.org/).**

It can read and write XML and XML-like data files in your application without requiring large non-standard libraries and Mini-XML only requires an ANSI C compatible compiler.

Comment: Thanks!! Is it platform specific? My application needs to be ported on windows, linux etc.

Comment: @user911747: It is available for Windows, Unix as well as Linux.

Comment: Thanks. One more query: minixml vs Expat/Xerces ? which is a better choice and when do we use what?

Comment: @user911747: There is no Best solution for all.It is a matter of choice, preference and requirements in some cases, You will have to read through the docummentation of these libraries(through links provided in answers here) & evaluate what best suits your purpose/requirement.

Answer (score 4):

"fopen()/fprintf()" will work just fine :)

"[Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/)" and "[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/)" are two very popular open-source libraries for XML.

Comment: Thanks!! I would explore both of them. Does any of these libraries give me some APIs to even parse an xml?

Comment: for just xml writing i would prefere this method but in case of reading xml file i use mxml...

Answer (score 3):

you can use [minixml](http://www.minixml.org/) or [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) library.

Comment: Thanks!! minixml vs Expat/Xerces ? which is a better choice and when do we use what?

Comment: @user911747: I use them for some small project, so for me both of them are good.

Comment: I found minixml to be super easy to get started.